# Comando Order by com acentuação no SQLite

Tags: sqlite, order

Estou programando para Android e utilizando o banco de dados nativo(`SQLite`). 
Quero fazer uma consulta na tabela de produtos ordenado pelo nome, mas ao fazer o `SELECT` assim:

```
SELECT * FROM produtos ORDER BY nome;
```

ele retorna, por exemplo:

```
Alvejante
Cloro
Sabão Liquido
Água Sanitária
```

Quero que o `SELECT` ignore a pontuação e tenha o seguinte retorno:

```
Água Sanitária
Alvejante
Cloro
Sabão Liquido
```

É possível fazer isso?

Comment: Tenta direto assim: `...ORDER BY nome COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`. Senão funcionar, tenta mudar o **COLLATE** do banco para o que coloquei na consulta.

Comment: estava testando essa solução.. sabia que funcionava no `where`, fui validar no `order by`.. =p

Comment: Tentei sua solução Diego, mas o Android Studio alegou "no such collation sequence: utf8_general_ci", de qualquer forma, obrigado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nesse caso você pode utilizar, um desses dois:

```
(SUA QUERY) ORDER BY NOME COLLATE UNICODE

(SUA QUERY) ORDER BY NOME COLLATE LOCALIZED
```

Segue a referência da documentação:

> Localized Collation - ORDER BY In addition to SQLite's default BINARY
>   collator, Android supplies two more, LOCALIZED, which changes with the
>   system's current locale, and UNICODE, which is the Unicode Collation
>   Algorithm and not tailored to the current locale.
>   [LINK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase)

- Tradução:

> Agrupamento localizado - ORDER BY Além do padrão BINARY do *collator* do SQLite,
>   o Android fornece mais dois, **LOCALIZED**, que muda com o
>   localidade atual do sistema e **UNICODE**, que é o algoritmo **Unicode Collation**
>   e não adaptado ao local atual.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente com o UNICODE. Obrigado!